# Classify a specific object amongst other diverse objects

Tags: classification, supervised-learning, computer-vision

I have a device which takes one picture per day of a slab. It contains many instances of a specific object (let's call it "Object A") and a few other objects (let's call them "Others").

I want to precisely count the number of "Objects A". With several successive processes I am able to get a bounding box around each object, then I want to pass the whole content of the bounding box to a supervised algorithm in order to classify them ; simple metrics such as area, color, etc., are not enough.

My problem is twofold :

- "Others" are about 5 % of the whole objects. Therefore it is very difficult to built a balanced database.
- "Others" are very diverse, so that there is no specific rule to recognize  "Others" rather than "Object A".

Is there a known method which works in this particular case (binary database with specific objects A but very diverse objects B) ? 
I tried an SVM but given the two problems listed above, it gave me bad results.

If there is a method where I don't need to specify an "Others" database at all, that would be great... Just a parameter to decide if my object is too far from my scatter plot or no.

Thanks you. :)